# How to deploy an angularcli-meteor project on Galaxy?

Tags: angular-meteor, angular2-meteor

Using [angularcli-meteor](https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor/tree/master/examples/angularcli-meteor), how to deploy an angularcli-meteor application on Galaxy since the meteor project itself is inside the "api" folder?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question in mind for a ionic 3 application, your API folder is a meteor project so you can deploy it on galaxy. And then host your Angular app else where if you make sure that your DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL points to this galaxy server.

You can set it DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL in bundler.config.json don't forget to re-generate your meteor-cliend-bundle.js file (npm run meteor-client:bundle) before deployment.